# Blogger - give each label a different color

Tags: conditional-statements, blogger

I'm trying to make each different label in Blogger have a different color, for example each hobbies label to be red, and each movies label to be blue, but it seems to change the color of every single label to red.

This is the current code I have:

```
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'> 
  <b:if cond='data:label.name == &quot;hobbies&quot;'>
    <style> .post-labels a { color: red; } </style> 
  </b:if> 
</b:loop>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way would be by adding a `class` to each label, for example add a class `.Movies` to label **Movies** and class named `.Hobbies` to label **Hobbies**. This way you can style each label from css rather than adding code for every label.

In this case all you have to do is add `expr:class='data:label.name'` to `<a>` tag, this will add class to each label with same name as label itself.

```
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
    <a expr:href='data:label.url' rel='tag' expr:class='data:label.name'><data:label.name/></a>
</b:loop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the default CSS and HTML code of labels intact, and instead of changing it, do this for each label:

```
a[href^="http://www.YOURSITE.com/search/label/CINEMA"] {
color: #colorcode !important;
background: #colorcode !important;
}
```

You can see I've added the entire label path for Cinema. Similarly, take full path of all labels and add different color rules for each label

For example, let's say one more label name is 'Television'.

You can add one more rule like this:

```
a[href^="http://www.YOURSITE.com/search/label/TELEVISION"] {
color: #colorcode !important;
background: #colorcode !important;
}
```

Color and background can be of your choice. Make sure you keep the !important directive intact.